# How do you use two scanners; one for reading line and onr for processing a line from console?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a method that reads a line from console consisting of two strings that enters them into a map, and the method will end when the user enters end. I am told to use two scanners; one for processing and one for reading each line, but the scanner that is suppose to be processing the line does not work. Any suggestion,tips,comments?

```
     TreeMap<String, String> map= new TreeMap<String,String>() {};
     String read="";
     String input="";
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     Scanner process= new Scanner(input);

     while(!"end".equals(input)){
     input=scanner.nextLine();
     read=process.nextLine();
     map.put(read, read);
     System.out.println(map);
     }
     scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would create the processing Scanner inside the loop with each line obtained.

```
while(!"end".equals(input)){
   input=scanner.nextLine();
   Scanner process = new Scanner(input);

   // .... etc....

   process.close();
}
```

As an aside, when asking questions, you'll want to post well-formatted code, including code with appropriate indentations. We're volunteers and greatly appreciate any effort you put in to make it easier to help you.